# how do i hide the bottom nav bar?

Tags: flutter, flutter-bottomnavigation

Using **persistent_bottom_nav_bar: ^5.0.2**, how do I detect that the user is scrolling on a list views of items on connection_view.dart page from bottom_nav_bar.dart page? So if it detects, I want the bottom_nav_bar to be hidden when user scrolls down.

**bottom_nav_bar.dart, my bottom navigation bar**

```
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Sizer(builder: ((context, orientation, deviceType) {
              return Scaffold(
                body: PersistentTabView(context,
                        screens: const [
                          ClientConnection(),
                          ClientDiscover(),
                          ClientDiscover(),
                          ClientDiscover()
                        ],
                        items: _navBarsItems(),
                        navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style1,
                        bottomScreenMargin: 0,
                        navBarHeight: 60,
                        padding: const NavBarPadding.all(5),
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          bottom: 15,
                          left: 20,
                          right: 20,
                        ),
                        decoration: NavBarDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                            boxShadow: const [
                              BoxShadow(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  blurRadius: 5,
                                  offset: Offset(2, 2))
                            ])),
        
              List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem> _navBarsItems() {
            return [
              PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
                icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                  'assets/active-connection-icon.svg',
                  width: 5.w,
                ),
                title: ("CONNECTIONS"),
                inactiveIcon: SvgPicture.asset(
                  'assets/inactive-connection-icon.svg',
                  width: 5.w,
                ),
              ),
              PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
                icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                  'assets/active-discover-icon.svg',
                  width: 5.w,
                ),
                title: ("DISCOVER"),
                inactiveIcon: SvgPicture.asset(
                  'assets/inactive-discover-icon.svg',
                  width: 5.w,
                ),
              ),
              PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
                icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                  'assets/active-profile-icon.svg',
                  width: 5.w,
                ),
                title: ("PROFILE"),
                inactiveIcon: SvgPicture.asset(
                  'assets/inactive-profile-icon.svg',
                  width: 5.w,
                ),
              ),
              PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
                icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                  'assets/active-notification-icon.svg',
                  width: 5.w,
                ),
                title: ("NOTIFICATIONS"),
                inactiveIcon: SvgPicture.asset(
                  'assets/inactive-notification-icon.svg',
                  width: 5.w,
                ),
              ),
```

**connection_view.dart,my list view of items**

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Sizer(builder: ((context, orientation, deviceType) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      elevation: 0,
      toolbarHeight: 10.h,
      title: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text(
            'Connections',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 2.w,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 10.w,
            height: 6.h,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    body: ListView.builder(
      controller: _scrollController,
      physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
      itemBuilder: (_, i) => ListTile(title: Text('Item $i')),
      itemCount: 20,
    ),
  );
}));
```

[image: sample]

Comment: can you share image ?what you exactly want?

Comment: shared. i want my bottom nav bar to hide when user scrolls down and then comes back up when users scrolls up

Answer (score 1):

You need two things: listen to scrolling events and update the visibility of your app bar accordingly.

To do that you will need a `StatefulWidget` which contains the app bar as well, create two members in the state class to track scrolling direction and app bar visibility:

```
bool _showAppBar = true;
bool _isScrollingDown = false;
```

Wrap the app bar into a `Visibility` widget depending on the `_showAppBar` member:

```
...
Visibility(visible: _showAppBar, child: YourBottomNavBarWidgetHere()),
...
```

Register the listener to detect scrolling direction and update the visibility. I suggest using `initState` and `dispose` methods:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
}

@override
void dispose() {
  _scrollController.removeListener(_scrollListener);
  super.dispose();
}

scrollListener() {
  if (_scrollController.position.userScrollDirection ==
      ScrollDirection.reverse && !_isScrollingDown) {
    _isScrollingDown = true;
    setState(() {
      _showAppBar = false;
    });
  }
  else if (_scrollController.position.userScrollDirection ==
      ScrollDirection.forward && _isScrollingDown) {
    _isScrollingDown = false;
    setState(() {
      _showAppBar = true;
    });
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use an `AnimatedContainer` instead of `Visibility`. This way the app bar will be hidden and shown animated:

```
AnimatedContainer(
  height: _showAppBar ? kToolbarHeight : 0.0,
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
  child: YourBottomNavBarWidgetHere()),
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your above code. I applied it on my ListView.builder in connection_view.dart but how do I detect it from my bottom_nav_bar.dart?

Comment: If you want to use it between widgets, you need to use ChangeNotifier or other state management instead of setState.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How do I implement that with ChangeNotifier?

Comment: Check [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple).

Comment: Thank you Peter. Will check it out.